# Android file upload error

Tags: android, upload

I've been pulling my hair from a long time..

I'm getting error on the last line here..

The error is:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error on token "uploaded_file", ,       expected
>     - String literal is not properly closed by a     double-quote

Any Help?

> public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
>
> ```
>       String fileName = sourceFileUri;
>
>       HttpURLConnection conn = null;
>       DataOutputStream dos = null; 
>       String lineEnd = "\r\n";
>       String twoHyphens = "--";
>       String boundary = "*****";
>       int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
>       byte[] buffer;
>       int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
>       File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
>
>       if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
>
>            dialog.dismiss();
>
>            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
>                                +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
>
>            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>                public void run() {
>                    messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
>                            +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
>                }
>            });
>
>            return 0;
>
>       }
>       else
>       {
>            try {
>
>                  // open a URL connection to the Servlet
>                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
>                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
>
>                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
>                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
>                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
>                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
>                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
>                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
>                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
>                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
>                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
>
>                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
>
>                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
>                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""
>                                          + fileName + "" + lineEnd);
> ```

Comment: You haven't escaped the double quotes around `"uploaded_file"`.  Should be like this `""uploaded_file""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes within the string with a backslash:

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"\" + fileName + \"\"" + lineEnd);
```